# Multiple Datepicker on form

Tags: jquery, date, input

My question may be repetitive but please go through once and guide.
I just need multiple input **datepicker** for the user.
I did change my class to **datepicker** and call .datepicker in jquery function.
But when I use other class `form-control` it didn't work.
I am unable to call different ids to the datepicker function.

```
$(function(id) {
  $('#doj' + id).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
});
```

Comment: well i change my class="form-control" to class="form-control datepicker". and call jquery as $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});. it works fine.

Comment: is that right to do. working fine...